# Scroll to Section

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have the following code, my question is how would I go about adding to this so that when a user clicks on a link a scroll to is added so that it takes them to the class .instructors section

```
<?php if($hasSections): ?>

                    <div class="instructors-links">
                        <?php foreach ($sections as $section): ?>
                            <a href="#section<?php echo $section['id']; ?>">
                                <div class="instructors-img">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $section['image']['url']; ?>" />
                                    <h2><?php echo $section['title']; ?></h2>
                                </div>
                            </a>

                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="instructors">
                        <?php foreach ($sections as $section): ?>

                            <section id="section<?php echo $section['id']; ?>">
                                <h1 class="section-title"><?php echo $section['title']; ?></h1>
                                <div class="section-content">
                                    <?php echo $section['content']; ?>
                                </div>
                            </section>

                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>



                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var $sections = jQuery('.instructors section'), //Each section of content
                            $sectionLinks = jQuery('.instructors-links a'); //Each section link

                        //When a section link <a> tag is clicked
                        $sectionLinks.click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default actions from happening like following the link and scrolling down to the content

                            changeSection(
                                jQuery(this).attr('href').replace('#', '') //Gets the href value of the clicked <a> tag and removes the "#" character
                            ); //Passes the section link to the "changeSection" function
                        });

                        changeSection('section1'); //When the page loads, display the "section1" section
                        function changeSection(sectionID) {
                            $sections.stop(true).hide(); //Stop animating and hide all sections
                            $sections.filter('#' + sectionID).stop(true).fadeIn(); //Display the section with the same ID as the section link that was clicked

                            $sectionLinks.removeClass('selected'); //Remove the selected class from all section link <a> tags
                            $sectionLinks.filter('[href="#' + sectionID + '"]').addClass('selected'); //Add the "selected" class to the section link that was clicked
                        }

                    </script>

                <?php endif; ?>
```

The idea is that when a user clicks on a link the text changes and the page scrolls down to the text.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or example we can see ? It's hard to understand how you're organizing your html.

Comment: I have edited the above

Answer (score 0):

this should animate a scroll to the '.instructors section'

```
 function changeSection(sectionID) {
        $sections.stop(true).hide(); //Stop animating and hide all sections
        $sections.filter('#' + sectionID).stop(true).fadeIn(); //Display the section with the same ID as the section link that was clicked

        $sectionLinks.removeClass('selected'); //Remove the selected class from all section link <a> tags
        $sectionLinks.filter('[href="#' + sectionID + '"]').addClass('selected'); //Add the "selected" class to the section link that was clicked

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $sections.offset().top
        }, 2000);

  }
```

Comment: Thanks Ran, this scrolls down to the text on entering the page but what I should have explained is that when a link is clicked the text inside the instructors section changes so every time a link is clicked the page should scroll down.

Comment: Oh i see! we have created a bug, it happends because we call this function on the page load, put the new code i have added to you remove it from the changeSection function and put it in youre click handler   - (  $sectionLinks.click(function(e) ) - this should do the trick, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a "helper" function in JS about scroll

```
function goToByScroll (id) {
    // Reove "link" from the ID
    id = id.replace("link", "");
    // Scroll
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
    },
        'slow');
}
```

you should pass the id and will work.

```
goToByScroll('section1');
```

Should locate the window in this id

Comment: Hi - I am not sure where all this goes?